# I am unable to align an HTML image to the text

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm new to web programming, and I'm having an annoying problem with HTML images alignment... I can't understand why images are always shifted down compared to text lying in the same line, regardless of its CSS settings!

```
<li class="navbar-item"><a class="nav-link" href="../contact/contact.php" >CONTACT</a></li>
<li class="navbar-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#"><img src="source" style="border-radius:10px;width:35px;height:35px;"></a></li>
```

This is the basic code I'm running, I've already tried plenty of methods to align "CONTACT" to the image, but no one of them works, giving me the same result:

[image: result]

Comment: Please consider creating a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your current issue with [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) for us.

Comment: For future questions, upload the exact code as image shows. We get nothing alike what you show us with your current code, and it makes it hard to replicate it / debug.

Answer (score 2):

You can use flexbox to align items very easily. The rule you need that aligns them vertically is "align-items: center;".

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

li {
list-style: none;
margin: 0 .5rem;
}

img {
  max-width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="navbar-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">CONTACT</a>
  </li>
  <li class="navbar-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">
    <img src="https://iconarchive.com/download/i47330/icons-land/vista-flags/United-States-Flag-1.ico">
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
display: inline;
```

to the image

Answer (score 0):

By default, li displays as list-item. If you change the display property of the element to "inline" it will be displayed next to the text.
Reference: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_default_values.asp

```html
<a class="nav-link" href="#">CONTACT</a>
  <a class="nav-link" href="#" style="display:inline"
    ><img src="source" style="border-radius:10px;width:35px;height:35px"
  /></a>
```

Thanks,
PNS